# CSS animation and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need help making an interactive website, similar to [briandelaney.com](http://briandelaney.com) . 
I especially want to incorporate the slide effect between links that the designer used. I read his code but I am not fluent in Javascript, but am familiar with Jquery.

I want to slide my menu when a link is clicked. How do I animate the CSS transforms with Javascript after this input? The section of code I want animated is on JSFiddle. Here's the code for the animation http://jsfiddle.net/1pc4f081/3/.

```
<section>
<div class='homecard' style="height:815px;">/* Initially, the menu is a card in the center of the page. I want this to slide to the top of the page when a link is clicked */
    <div class="menu home appear" id="mainmenu">
        <ul>
            <li class="hover-effect1">  <a href="/about" class="main-menu about-link">
                        <span class="effect" data-hover="About">
                            <span class="what">
                                <span> About</span>
                            </span>
                        </span>
                    </a>

                <div class="border right">
                    <div></div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="hover-effect">   <a href="/services" class="main-menu service-link">
                            <span class="effect" data-hover="Services">
                                <span class="what">
                                    <span> Services</span>
                                    </span>
                                    </span>
                                    </a>

                <div class="border right">
                    <div></div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="hover-effect 3"> <a href="contact" class="main-menu contact-link">
                            <span class="effect" data-hover="Contact">
                                <span class="what">
                                    <span> Contact</span>
                                    </span>
                                    </span>
                                    </a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.homecard {
-webkit-animation-name: pushHeaderUp;
-moz-animation-name:pushHeaderUp;
animation-name:pushHeaderUp;
-moz-animation-duration:3s;
-moz-animation-iteration-count:1;
-moz-animation-timing-function:ease;
-moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
-webkit-animation-duration:3s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count:1;
-webkit-animation-timing-function:ease;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
animation-duration:3s;
animation-timing-function:ease;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
```

}

```
@keyframes pushHeaderUp {
0% {
    -webkit-transform:translateY(0px);
    transform:translateY(0px);
    -moz-transform:transloateY(0px)
}
60% {
    -webkit-transform:translateY(-180px);
    transform:translateY(180px);
    -moz-transform:translateY:(-180px)
}
100% {
    -webkit-transform:translateY(-240px);
    transform:translateY(-240px);
    -moz-transform:translateY(-240px)
}
```

}

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.main-menu').click(function () {
    $('.homecard').addClass('.pushHeaderUp');
});
```

Comment: Your question is way too vague. Please cut your issue in little, and take each problem to try solve them by reading documentation and so. If you don't find the solution, come here and explain brefly your matter and don't forget to link the problematic code involved. Please be aware we cannot create a website for you !

Comment: I think he's asking for some 'tips & tricks', frameworks, whatever in order to achieve the same design but for sure you right about let him provide some code / thoughts about what he wants to

Comment: I edited the question.  I want to focus on .click . I already have the layout of the website finished. I just need help with the framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can read about [silde()](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_slide.asp) and [animate()](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_animate.asp) functions in jQuery framework. I think it will help you to build what you want and get deeper into animations topic.

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with those functions, but when I use them I never see the animation after clicking a link. It only shows the end result.

Comment: How about animation in demo applications for example: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_animation1_multicss 
 Does it work? If not, you have problem with browser, maybe old version... if they work you have problem with your code. Then install some debug tools like FireBug for FireFox and follow the code step-by-step.